# Clean up Validation Logic, Avoid Using Too Many If Statments

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am currently writing a validation that reads data from an api and checks for differet "domaintypes". There are 6 domaintypes types in total (windows, low, high, and dot, linux low, high, and dot) that need to present, I am currently checking by using a bunch of if statements, but I feel like it's super drawn out and messy. I've been trying to tweak it to make it more concise, but it keeps messing with the logic and I don't get what I need. I'm fairly new to c# so I'm probably missing something super obvious. Here is the current code below:

```
// get api response
 var products = responseProvider.GetServiceResponse
            var count = 0;
            List<string> missingdomainskus = new List<string>();

            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                var productInfo = responseProvider.GetProductResponse(product).Result;
                var skus = productInfo.Skus;
                foreach (Sku sku in skus)
                {
                    string Name = sku.Aspects[Name];
                    if (sku.Aspects.ContainsKey(Item) && Item.Equals("Dot", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && sku.Aspects[Group].Contains("Windows"))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (sku.Aspects.ContainsKey(Item) && Item.Equals("Low", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && sku.Aspects[Group].Contains("Windows"))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
//Null orwhitespace = "high"
                    if ((!sku.Aspects.ContainsKey(Item) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Item)) && sku.Aspects[Group].Contains("Windows"))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (sku.Aspects.ContainsKey(Item) && Item.Equals("Dot", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !sku.Aspects[Group].Contains("Windows"))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (sku.Aspects.ContainsKey(Item) && Item.Equals("Low Priority", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !sku.Aspects[Group].Contains("Windows"))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if ((!sku.Aspects.ContainsKey(Item) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Item)) && !sku.Aspects[Group].Contains("Windows"))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (count < 6)
                    {
                        missingdomainskus.Add(Name);
                    }
            }
        }
            if (missingdomainskus.Any())
            {
                string convert = string.Join(",", missingdomainskus);
                throw new CheckException($"These skus are missing domains: : {convert} i. There should be 6-7 domains per sku");
            }
```

Comment: It kind of seems like you are increasing the value of `count` regardless of the input received. In this condition, you can replace your entire foreach section including every if statement with `count = skus.Count`

Comment: @ExplodatedFaces I'm not counting the skus though, I'm counting the domain types. There are some skus that do not have the domain types in the if statements so the counter shouldn't increase if he domain type is not present.

Comment: Can a sku exist with a false value of Aspects.ContainsKey? I'm just thinking of some different ways this can be simplified, for example if we know every sku has a key `Item` we might be able to make it a switch statement which would be faster operating and easier to read for humans

Comment: @ExplodatedFaces Unfortunately not ever sku has the Item key :(